# Best way to modify the fields in response in django rest?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer that gives this data

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'cost', 'currency')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posts = PostSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

and it gives the response like this,

```java
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "joe",
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 20,
            "name": "first post",
            "cost": 20.00,
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        {
            "id": 21,
            "name": "second post",
            "cost": 30.00,
            "currency": "USD"
        }
    ]
}
```

However I want to change/add the fields of the response based on few conditions,
Eg. if cost is less than 25, make it zero and add a discount field for every post.

This is how I am doing.

```py
class MyPostView(APIView):
    def get(request):
        query_set = User.objects.all()
        user_and_posts = UserSerializer(query_set)
        response_data = user_and_posts.data

        # I am modifying the serializer data here :<
        for post in response_data['posts']:
            post['discount'] = 10 # some value
            if post['cost'] < 25: 
                post['cost'] = 0

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

To me modifying the primitive data like this is not looking right,
is there any alternate way in django rest to do this?
or could've done better with serializer?

In general, what's the best way to alter the response data we get from `serializer` and
format it in the way client wants? In languages like Java, we will have serializer for model and another serializer for output.. Can I do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

If it is something that is model related and can be derived by manipulating model variables, I would advise to add properties into your model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    @property
    def alternative_cost(self):
        if self.cost < 25:
            return 0
        else:
            return self.cost
```

Then you have to add the newly created property to serializer.

Comment: What I meant was there can be many fields which might be changing, what's the best way to handle that, assuming none of the fields are model related?

Comment: I provided one of the use cases, and how it can be handled.

Comment: I don't want the data coming from the model to be changed. The reason is I have multiple serializers utilizing the same model.

Comment: By adding a functional property, you are not modifying data in the database, you just derive an info, that you intend to use regularly. The next step is to create serializers that match your needs.